# AWK Escape Characters Confusion

Tags: bash, awk

So I've been doing some reading on AWK but I seem to be having a problem executing the following code:

```
curl http://website.com/users.csv | tac | tac | sed '101,400!d' | grep "female" |
awk -F',' '{ print "sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female" " " $1 " " "-c" " " \"$5 " " $6\""}' |
bash
```

I'm trying to escape the double quotes immediately before `$5` and after `$6` so that I can either do a system call from AWK or just pipe to bash. For some reason my escape characters are not working. I read this [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html) summary on escape sequences to no avail.

How can I accomplish this?

The output should look like this:

```
sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female dinessid1965 -c "Marina Propst"
```

And the input looks like this:

```
reatim,Shephoi8v,female,Ms.,Eija,Kankkunen,4721 Pearcy Avenue,Fort Wayne,IN,46804,,260-715-7242,2/22/84,Pisces,Dermatologist
```

Comment: Why are you running the page through `tac` twice?  That's an expensive no-op. It looks like it should work as-is, although it will put two spaces between the first and last name instead of only one.  Please provide some sample input and actual vs. desired output.

Comment: Hi @MarkReed, you're right about `tac`. I forgot to delete it, I was using it `tac` twice because I was using `curl` and then piping to `head` and was getting a _curl: (23) Failed writing body (1926...)_ message, so I used `tac` twice to fix that. I included some sample input now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, for the escaping: you make your life harder than necessary by quoting everything separately. Instead of

```
print "sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female" " " $1 " " "-c" " " \"$5 " " $6\""
```

you could write

```
print "sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female " $1 " -c " \"$5 " " $6\""
```

at which point it becomes a little more obvious that there is something off with the quoting: GNU Awk complains that the `\` is not the last character of the line.

You could write it like this, with the escaped quote `\"` between quotes:

```
print "sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female " $1 " -c \"" $5 " " $6 "\""
```

or, easier to read, specify a variable that contains the double quote (see the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html)):

```
awk -v dq='"' '{ print "sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female " $1 " -c " dq $5 " " $6 dq }'
```

Secondly, your whole chain can be simplified: `tac | tac` does nothing, and what grep and sed do can be done by awk:

```
curl http://website.com/users.csv |
awk -F, -v dq='"' '/female/ && NR >= 101 && NR <= 400 { \
 print "sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female " dq $1 dq " -c " dq $5 " " $6 dq }' |
bash
```

Alternatively, to avoid some of the ugliness of adding spaces between variables using `print`, we could use `printf` (thanks to [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) for the nudge):

```
curl http://website.com/users.csv |
awk -F, '/female/ && NR >= 101 && NR <= 400 { \
printf "sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female \"%s\" -c \"%s %s\"\n", $1, $5, $6 }' |
bash
```

Notice how also the expansion of `$1` is quoted in the last two commands to prevent side effects of characters special to the shell (or even malicious commands).

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, thank you very much for your answer. I removed the double quote preceding the last slash from your answer and it worked: `print "sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female " $1 " -c \"" $5" " $6 "\""` The output is as expected. I'm seeing the quotes, in groups, like this: _"sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female "_, then _" -c \""_, then _" "_, and finally the last group _"\""_.  If it's like this, the last group confuses me because you're escaping the quote by doing `\"`. I'm guessing you need the double quotes around the escaped double quote to include it in the string?

Comment: @ReneAlejandroSantiago Ha, there was a quote too many! I've removed it. To print just a single quote, you could write `print "\""`: an escaped quote `\"` between quotes `" "`. It looks weird, and I prefer the method with assigning to a variable.

Comment: Great! Yeah, I supposed it was because the double quote itself needs to be printed, which makes sense. Anyway, you're completely right, the variable assignment approach is easier on the eyes and avoids having to escape the double quote itself as the variable is interpolated by the terminal? Thank you very much @BenjaminW.

Comment: @ReneAlejandroSantiago If you declare it as a variable, the shell leaves it alone as it is in single quotes, and later the shell only sees `dq` - only awk knows about that variable.

Comment: I think `printf "sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female %s -c \"%s %s\"\n", $1, $5, $6 }'` is clearer and simpler FWIW. I also think you should be quoting the expansion of `$1` as well: `printf "sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female \"%s\" -c \"%s %s\"\n", $1, $5, $6 }'` to protect it from all the shell nastiness you'll get if `$1` contains globbing chars etc..

Comment: @EdMorton Yes! Added.

Answer (score 1):

You're making this harder than necessary by involving awk at all. It's also dangerous because you're not quoting the contents of `$1`, `$5`, and `$6` for the shell. If they contain any funny characters, you're in trouble.

You can do it entirely in bash, safely:

```
curl http://website.com/users.csv | sed '101,400!d' | grep "female" |
while IFS=, read -a words; do
    sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female "${words[0]}" -c "${words[4]} ${words[5]}"
done
```

Although for more safety you might need to ensure that the username field doesn't contain anything fishy (e.g. start with `../`). I don't know how much checking `useradd` does.

Comment: `$1`, `$5` and `$6` are within single quotes, how are their contents "not quoted for the shell"?

Comment: They're in double-quotes, aren't they, @BenjaminW.?  At least, `$5` and `$6` are; `$1` is not quoted in the output in the question.

Comment: But they're in double quotes like this: `print ' "$1" '` and the shell doesn't interpolate between single quotes: `var=test; echo '"$var"'` results in `"$var"`.

Comment: The awk script is in single quotes. Awk sets, and then interpolates,`$5` and `$6`, constructing a command that it then passes to another invocation of the shell. What happens if `$5` or `$6` (as set by awk) contains a double-quote? That double-quote will be passed through, unescaped, to the shell, which will think it ends the double-quoted string. E.g. if `$5` is `"; rm -rf /; "` (the double-quotes are part of the value of `$5`) then the command will be `sudo useradd -Db /home/gender/female dinessid1965 -c ""; rm -rf /; " Propst"` and you just blew away your filesystem.

Comment: *Now* I get it! I ignored the `| bash` the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

you're using too many quotes!

Here is a simple example you can change into your format

```
$ echo dinessid1965,two,three,four,Marina,Propst |
   awk -F, -v q='"' '{print "sudo ...", $1, "-c", q $5, $6 q}'  

sudo ... dinessid1965 -c "Marina Propst"
```